# kafka stream client shutdown

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an apache kafka streams application . I notice that it sometimes shutsdown when a rebalancing occurs with no real reason for the shutdown . It doesn't even throw an exception.

Here are some logs on the same

```
[2022-03-08 17:13:37,024] INFO [Consumer clientId=svc-stream-collector-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=svc-stream-collector] Adding newly assigned partitions:  (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2022-03-08 17:13:37,024] ERROR stream-thread [svc-stream-collector-StreamThread-1] A Kafka Streams client in this Kafka Streams application is requesting to shutdown the application (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread)
[2022-03-08 17:13:37,030] INFO stream-client [svc-stream-collector] State transition from REBALANCING to PENDING_ERROR (org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams)
old state:REBALANCING new state:PENDING_ERROR
[2022-03-08 17:13:37,031] INFO [Consumer clientId=svc-stream-collector-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=svc-stream-collector] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2022-03-08 17:13:37,032] INFO stream-thread [svc-stream-collector-StreamThread-1] Informed to shut down (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread)
[2022-03-08 17:13:37,032] INFO stream-thread [svc-stream-collector-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_REVOKED to PENDING_SHUTDOWN (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread)
[2022-03-08 17:13:37,067] INFO stream-thread [svc-stream-collector-StreamThread-1] Thread state is already PENDING_SHUTDOWN, skipping the run once call after poll request (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread)
[2022-03-08 17:13:37,067] WARN stream-thread [svc-stream-collector-StreamThread-1] Detected that shutdown was requested. All clients in this app will now begin to shutdown (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread)
```

I'm suspecting its because there are no `newly assigned partitions in the log below`

```
[2022-03-08 17:13:37,024] INFO [Consumer clientId=svc-stream-collector-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=svc-stream-collector] Adding newly assigned partitions:  (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
```

However I'm not exactly sure why this error occurs . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Got my answer to this here - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13740